# windows 10 python modulenotfounderror

Tags: python-3.x, flask, windows-10

I have an issue with Python 3.6.3 on Windows 10.

I have installed flask_bootstrap. Here is my (edited) pip freeze:

```
C:\Users\pablo\willwriter2>pip freeze

Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
```

When I run a very simple script:

```
from flask import Flask
from bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

@app.routes('/')
def homepage():
    return "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
```

I get the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\pablo\willwriter2\main2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bootstrap import Bootstrap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap'
```

This error occurs whether I use a virtual environment or the global python install. It has occurred for other modules as well.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: it should be `from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap`

Comment: @TomásAntunes thanks